# Проблема с json в Python

Tags: python, json

Я столкнулся с проблемой при парсе json формата в python

Код ошибки:
`KeyError: 'id'`

```
import json


parse = input("Username:   ")

url = ('https://www.instagram.com/'+ parse +'/?__a=1')

data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
output = json.loads(data)
print ("ip",output['id'] )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

смотрите внимательно вложенную структуру в `JSON`. Поле `id` находится в  словаре `user` , а словарь `user` в словаре `graphql`
В итоге получить `id` можно так

```
print("id",output['graphql']['user']['id'])
```